# Post content not showing

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this code that works perfect:

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<span><?php the_date('m/d/y'); ?></span>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button>Read More</button></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I want to display an excerpt of the post content between the date and button. So I added `<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>`. Didn't work. I tried `<p><?php get_the_content(); ?></p>`. Still nothing.

I tried putting the `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>` `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` loop around all of the HTML and just the paragraph. Both yielded nothing.

How do I get the excerpt to display?

Comment: You may want to post this question on [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com). For example, [Accessing the post content with WP_Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176506/accessing-the-post-content-with-wp-query).

Comment: Great! Thank you